# injection $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions

Today a friend of mine told me a nice fact, but we couldn't prove it. The fact is that there is an injection $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ defined by the fomula $(m,n)\mapsto (m+n)^{\max\{m,n\}}$, where $\mathbb{N}$ denotes the natural numbers.

How to prove that this map is injective? It should be elementary. We might be overlooking something trivial.

Thanks!

**Edit** As it was pointed out, it is not an injection by easy reasons. Thanks a lot! I was just overcomplicating things. But what if we restrict the map to the set of pairs $(m,n)$ such that $m>n$?

Comment: GitGud and Antonio, thanks for your comments! I've edited the question.

Comment: The restriction of the function to $\{(m,n)\in\mathbb N^2:m\le n\}$ seems to be injective. Perhaps you can post a separate question.

Comment: If $m > n$, then $\max\{m, n\}=m$, so the map is just $(m, n) \mapsto (m + n)^m$.

Comment: For anyone else who was looking for it, here's a [newer question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/450723/an-injection-into-mathbbn) asking if it is injective restricted to $m \le n$.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is not an injection since $m+n=n+m$ and $\max(m,n)=\max(n,m)$.

Answer (score 4):

Is not. For example $(3,2)$ and $(2,3)$ are both mapped to $5^3$.

Answer (score 1):

A simple injection is given by $(m,n) \mapsto 2^m 3^n$.

Comment: The OP never asked for an injection.

Comment: A theoretical downvote for your comment, @GitGud

Comment: @TheChaz2.0 ^_^

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, this is not injective because we can freely swap $m$ and $n$ in your map and we get the same answer. However, try a map along the lines of $(m,n)\rightarrow 2^m\times 3^n$, are you okay with showing that this is injective?

Comment: The OP never asked for an injection.

Comment: @GitGud That doesn't mean this is not an useful answer, though.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff Should I go give 'useful' answers unrelated to the questions?

Comment: Just lol at people upvoting the comment above.