# an injection into $\mathbb{N}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions

Is that true that the map $f\colon \{(m,n)\in\mathbb N^2:m\le n\}\to\mathbb N$ defined by $(m,n)\mapsto (m+n)^{\max\{m,n\}}$ is an injection? If it is, how to prove that? I have asked a similar [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/450703/injection-mathbbn-times-mathbbn-to-mathbbn) but it appeared to be very easy. My original struggling in the previous question was that I assumed that $m\leq n$ instead of checking easy reasons for the map not to be injective.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $f(m,n)=f(m',n')$, i.e. $(m+n)^n=(m'+n')^{n'}$.  If $n=n'$ we get $m'=m$, so assume without loss of generality that $n<n'$.  If $m+n\le m'+n'$, then $$(m+n)^{\max(m,n)}=(m+n)^n< (m+n)^{n'}\le (m'+n')^{n'}=(m'+n')^{\max(m',n')}$$
so $f(m,n)\neq f(m',n')$.  Hence we may conclude $m+n>m'+n'$.

Write $a=m+n, b=m'+n'$, with $a^{n}=b^{n'}$, an integer assumed bigger than 1.  For any prime $p$ dividing both $a,b$ we have $n\nu_p(a)=n'\nu_p(b)$, so $\nu_p(a)>\nu_p(b)$.  Hence $b|a$, and since they are unequal $a\ge 2b$ or $$m+n\ge 2(m'+n')$$

On the other hand, since $m\le n<n'$, we have $$(m+n)^n<(2(m'+n'))^n$$

Edit: $\nu_p(x)$ denotes the [valuation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_order), i.e. the maximum number of $p$'s that divide integer $x$.

Comment: That's nice! Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome, glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

$$(2n)^n-(n+2)^{(n+1)}>0.$$

...

for $n$ large (starting from not so large).

Comment: I would like to see an elaboration of your idea then.